# Multiprocessing: How to use pool.map on a list and function with arguments?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some misunderstandings with multiprocessing and map function.

I'll try to describe briefly:

Firstly, I have an list, for instance:

```
INPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE = [
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
    ['https://github.com', 'Owner', 'Repo', '', '', '0', '0'],
]
```

Also I have method, which currently parsing this list using specific internal logic:

```
def parse(api_client1, api_client2):
     for row in INPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE: 
         parsed_repo_row = ... (some logic with row)
         OUTPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE.append(parsed_repo_row)
```

Finally, I've red that there is some variants to make it async instead of `for`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(10)
    pool.map(<???>, INPUT_MAGIC_STRUCTURE)
```

`???` – I cannot understand how to transfer my `parse()` from `for row in INPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE` as a first argument to `pool.map()` and transfer all its arguments — api_client1, api_client2.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

I've already made:

```
pool = Pool(10)
pool.map(parse(magic_parser, magic_staff), INPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE)
```

Anyway, when interpreter comes to the second line it stops and makes only one instance of parse() method (I see the logging output of parsed rows: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 – one by one).

Comment: So, you'll have many processes running on a list modifying it?

Comment: @TimGivois Suppose that these processes will only append to the list. It is not possible?

Comment: It is possible, if you are only appending to the list, because 'appends' are thread safe, that mean, that you can have x processes running concurrently modifying the list without any problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `(some logic with row)` in a function:

```
def row_logic(row):
    return result
```

Pass the function to `Pool.map`:

```
pool = Pool(10)
pool.map(row_logic, INPUT_MAGIC_DATA_STRUCTURE)
```

Answer (score -1):

We'll, in python it's not that easy. You need to map your rows to your parse per row function. Look at this link: https://gist.github.com/baojie/6047780

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def parse_row(row):
    (some logic with row)

def dispatch_job(rows, parse_row):
    for row in rows:
         p = Process(target=parse_row, args=(row,))
         p.start()
```